# Add Multiple Columns to SQL

Tags: sql, reportbuilder

First off, I don't know much at all about SQL, I'm just modifying a report built by our developers. I need to add about 100 blank columns to the end of this report (however dumb that sounds). Is there an easier way than right click->add column X 100?

Comment: Could you explain why you would want to do this? Maybe someone could recommend a better solution for you if we understood the purpose.

Comment: The columns will not remain blank but instead they will have labels and some will have variables in them. The purpose is that this report is used to download information from the server in an organized way in order to easily upload it to a reporting service, rather than running a query everyday. The reporting requirements have changed, so the report needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit the RDL directly by opening it up in a text editor and altering the columns in that fashion

as you have already alluded to however this design sounds like a bad idea

is there any opportunity to use a Pivot / Matrix instead? i would imagine the very fact they are to remain blank would exclude that

Comment: I had opened it in notepad but I quickly realized that i was in over my head. I agree that other things might work better, but i'm stuck with this framework and trying to make it work the easiest way possible.

Comment: maybe an opportunity to learn :) have a try and if you cannot succeed try posting what you have attempted here